# Date comparison in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I have two variable `TO_DATE` and `FROM_DATE`. My table has two fields `DOJ` and `DOL`. I want to select all the records where `DOJ < TO_DATE and DOL > FROM_DATE`.

How can I write an SQL query in for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might run into troubles with the variable named to_date, since that is a built-in Oracle command. You can work around that using double quotes wherever the variable is used, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE doj < "to_date" AND dol > from_date;
```

Comment: Yes, it's important to avoid confusion with the TO_DATE built-in Oracle function, great consideration ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you would like to do.

## FIRST INTERPRETATION

I want to select all the records whose DOJ < TO_DATE and, IN THE MEANTIME, DOL > FROM_DATE.

```
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
 WHERE DOJ < "TO_DATE" AND DOL > "FROM_DATE"; -- using double quotes in order to
                                              -- avoid confusion with TO_DATE
                                              -- built-in function with the same name.
                                              -- Thanks to kicsit ;-)
```

## SECOND INTERPRETATION

I want to select all the records whose DOJ < TO_DATE and, SEPARATELY, DOL > FROM_DATE.

```
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
 WHERE DOJ < "TO_DATE"
UNION -- UNION ALL substituted with UNION, thanks to kicsit user ;-)
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
 WHERE DOL > "FROM_DATE";
```

... or - that is the same:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MY_TABLE 
 WHERE DOJ < "TO_DATE" OR DOL > "FROM_DATE";
```

Comment: The two queries in the "Second Interpretation" do not produce the same results, since UNION ALL will produce duplicates of all rows that satisfy both condition.

Comment: You are right! ;-)
I've SUBSTITUTED "UNION ALL" with "UNION", which REMOVE DUPLICATES ;-)